# Using Webrat to check a list has a specific number of li elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, webrat

For a cucumber step, I know that a particular `ul` element should have 5 children `li`. How can I assert this with Webrat?

I'm guessing there could be something like:

`Then ".selector" should have n ".another-selector"`

or maybe

`Then I should see n ".selector" within ".another.selector"`

Is there anything like this floating around, or should I make a custom step?

Thanks!

---

*Update:*

I've resorted to the following, which seems to work fine:

```
# Check there are the correct number of items
assert_have_selector("#activity ol li:nth-child(5)")
assert_have_no_selector("#activity ol li:nth-child(6)")
```

---

*Another update:*

I've made a little change to what Matt has supplied:

```
Then /^I should see ([0-9]+) "([^\"]*)"$/ do |count, selector|
  response.body.should have_selector(selector, :count => count.to_i)
end
```

Works a treat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
Then /^"([^\"]*)" should have ([0-9]+) "([^\"]*)"$/ do |selector1, count, selector2|
  within(selector1) do |content|
       content.should have_selector(selector2, :count => count.to_i)
  end
end
```

That oughta do the trick?

Matta